# Setting the out parameter in callable statement

Tags: java, stored-procedures, jdbc, callable, out-parameters

I'm trying to run a stored procedure that returns a resultSet using oracle jdbc.
The procedure is as follows.

```
create or replace procedure display_players (rset OUT sys_refcursor)
as
Begin
open rset for select * from player_data;
End;
/
```

The java code is as follows

```
try {
sql = "{call display_players()}";
call = conn.prepareCall(sql);
call.execute();
rs = call.getResultSet();

while(rs.next()){
    System.out.println(rs.getString("name") + " : " + rs.getString("club"));
}
```

I tried to register the out parameter as

```
call = conn.prepareCall("{call display_players(?)}");
call.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
```

But that dint work nor is the current code working as i get a null pointer exception which means the result set is not being returned.
how do i achieve this?

Comment: can you post error code.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at tester.main(tester.java:49)

Comment: please post your whole error code.

Comment: That's the error code with oracleTypes.cursor

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'DISPLAY_PLAYERS'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Comment: at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:951)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:513)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:227)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.doOall8(T4CCallableStatement.java:205)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.executeForRows(T4CCallableStatement.java:1043)

Comment: at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1336)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3613)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.execute(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3714)

Comment: at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.execute(OracleCallableStatement.java:4755)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.execute(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1378)
 at tester.main(tester.java:42)

Comment: That's the entire code for not registering the output parameter

Answer (score 2):

I think you haven't quite worked out how to get the result set from an `OUT` parameter from a stored procedure call.

Firstly, you need to register the `OUT` parameter, as in your second code sample:

```
call = conn.prepareCall("{call display_players(?)}");
call.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
```

However, once you've executed the statement, it's not correct to `call.getResultSet()` to get at the result set in the `OUT` parameter.  For example, suppose you were calling a stored procedure that had two `OUT` parameters returning cursors.  Which one should `call.getResultSet()` return?

The trick is to use `call.getObject(...)` to get the value of the parameter from `call` as an `Object` and then cast this to a `ResultSet`.  In other words, replace the line

```
rs = call.getResultSet();
```

with

```
rs = (ResultSet)call.getObject(1);
```